# Custom Mail Merge Button to skip Page with Generate button

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, email-template, mail-merge

I am trying to create a custom mail merge button that skils the Generate page. I started out with this URL in a dev environment using the below for formula :

```
 IF(CONTAINS($Profile.Name,"Business Consultant")|| CONTAINS($Profile.Name,"System Administrator"), if ( ISPICKVAL(Exhibit_Status__c, "Pending Customer Signature"), 
 if ( ISBLANK( MailMergeTemplateId__c) , MailMergeTemplate__c, 
 HYPERLINK("/mail/mmchoose.jsp?save=1&p7=0&p8=" & LEFT(MailMergeTemplateId__c,15) & "&id=" & Id & "&1=" & Name & "&retURL=%2F" &   , IMAGE('/resource/1450444732000/Generate','Generate'), '_top') & BR() &     'Template: "' & MailMergeTemplate__c & '"'), '') , '')
```

It works to get me to the generate page and the appropriate template is already selected as well as the task checkbox unchecked. **I would like to skip this page. The users want to be able to click the button and just have the appropriate mail merge template generate.**

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not quite following. The template is selected but the task checkbox is unselected. Are you asking how modify your button to set the the task as selected and save what you have so that the template generates?

Comment: @crmprogdev : No, I am asking how I can modify the logic for the custom mail merge button so that the page with the template selection and task selection is skipped. When the custom mail merge button is clicked from a record detail page, the mail merge template should be automatically selected and sent and I should be returned to the record detail page. An email should be sent to me with the merge document containing the record merge details. The page with the Generate button should not appear.

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Can anyone provide an answer? Any help will be appreciated.